# command for multiple input and multiple output with different extension

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am performing some operations using the grep, sed, and cut commands on a Linux machinete:

```
zgrep -A1 "^module" *.v.gz | sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' | cut -f1 -d"("
```

This is being run on files with the file extension .v.gz and I want the output files to have
.txt extension instead.

For example, input filename:

```
abcd.v.gz
efgh.v.gz
ijkl.v.gz
mnop.v.gz
```

output filename

```
abcd.txt
efgh.txt
ijkl.txt
mnop.txt
```

So I want to keep the same file name prefix but change the extension. How can I do this for an arbitrary number of files?

I am not looking for shell primitive

Comment: Are you asking how to put the output of the zgrep|sed|cut pipeline into files which match the input file but with a different extension?

Comment: @icarus yes I want to store output into the same file name but .txt extension the input file extension is .v.gz

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to process each file

```
for f in *.v.gz
do
    zgrep -A1 "^module" "$f" | 
    sed -n -e 's/^\(module \)*\(.*(.*)\).*$/\2/p' |
    cut -f1 -d"(" > "${f%.v.gz}.txt"
done
```

I have a slight doubt about the sed program, I would have guessed that you wanted

```
sed -n -e 's/^module *\([^(]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

and then you don't need the cut at all.

Comment: your guess is correct but in sed, I am taking data between two strings there is no limit for lines..   in your code it'll consider only one line(module ).

Comment: My point is more that you don't need to post process sed output with cut, you can just choose to print less with sed.

Comment: i used your command but i am not getting the answer what i want

Comment: Can you add some sample output from the zgrep to the question?